# Cannot figure out how to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like a home button on all my actives so they can bring you to the starting point.  I got some great help from stack overflow and a link to the document in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I'm assuming I will have to set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag,
the document ion has the following line

When starting an activity, you can modify the default association of an activity to its task by including flags in the intent that you deliver to startActivity(). The flags you can use to modify the default behavior are:
Ok I tried the following,

```
 new Intent(this,TellaFortuneActivity.class,  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
```

and

```
 startActivity(i,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
 break;
```

both gave me errors.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,TellaFortuneActivity.class);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Or alternatively use [`addFlags(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags%28int%29) to add additional flags, in stead of replacing the one(s) already present.